Oauth2 flow / State validation with redirect endpoint on the frontend side
I have a question regarding oauth2 flow. I am using python/fastapi and I have implemented oauth2 flow, where the redirect endpoint is on the front end side because the backend isn't accessible from the outside. The flow looks like this

FE send login request to BE
BE, generates state in request.session and redirects request to Identity Provider
IDP validates input and redirect request to the given redirect url
FE receives auth code and state and sends authorize request on the BE
BE validates state AND HERE IS THE PROBLEM, he receives new session, BANG, can't validate received input.
Access token validation ....

The FE is using react js and simply receives code and state from IDP and forwards it. What would be the issue? Should frontend process the request in such a manner that it wouldn't lose the session or maybe request.session isn't a good choice (oauth2 lib implementation do the same).
I was testing it locally, so session resetting on different domain shouldn't be the case. It was working without redirect endpoint, when redirect url was on the BE.

If you are losing the session after the redirect back from the IDP, that is most likely an issue with the SameSite attribute of your session cookie. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#samesitesamesite-value

I checked what do i set for this attribute and it had Lax and even checked that with None. So it wasn't the issue.

For anyone looking for a solution for a similar situation. I didn't find a perfect solution for my problem, I had to change how redirect url endpoint is working, previously it was directly redirecting the request to the Identity provider service and I changed that to simple return a 200 and redirect url as string, which frontend sets in an anchor in href. After that it doesn't run into CORS issue as the browser doesn't check it.
